# How to save a file as apk without increasing in size in Android (can not install it)

Tags: android, installation, local-storage

I try to download file from server and save it in internel storage and then install it.
I downloaded it using retrofit by this code

```
 Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getNewVersion();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, 
 Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() ) {
                Log.d("1", "server contacted and has file");

                boolean writtenToDisk = 
 writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());

                Log.d("2", "file download was a success? " + writtenToDisk);
            } else {
                Log.d("3", "server contact failed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("4", "error");
        }
    });
```

and I saved it by this code

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
    try {
        // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
        File futureStudioIconFile = new 
File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "app-debug.apk");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d("TAG", "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " 
   + fileSize);
            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

its original 4.56MB but it shows 6.08MB in Android storage.
When I open it to install it shows
[version N /A size N/ A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCG8B.png)
and when I try to install it, it shows this [parse problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsnms.png)

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?
How to remove extra bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you use `HttpResponseMessage.content` in your web service method because a normal return will not be a standard size for the file that you want:

```
[HttpGet] 
[Route("api/Depository/DownloadFileFTP")]  // /{pass}
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFileFTP() //string pass
{  
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    string ftphost = "*******";
    string ftpfilepath = "/app-debug.apk";
    byte[] fileData;

    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;

    using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
    {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("**", "****");
        fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);
    }
    byte[] bytes = fileData;               
    result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
    System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "app.apk";
    return result;
}
```